# is it possible to hide/show standard/custom buttons based on profile in the same pagelayout

Tags: page-layout, pagelayoutassignment

How to show/hide the buttons in the standard page  layout based on profiles without using visual force page and without creating different page layouts.is it posible to achieve in the same layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to use multiple page layouts. This is why the profile page layout assignment exists--to provide different users different experiences, such as field availability and editability, as well as which buttons and related lists are available to the user on a per-profile basis. However, some buttons also respect profile permissions. For example, the Delete button won't generally appear on records the user cannot delete, and the Edit button won't generally appear on records the user cannot edit.

Comment: is it not possible to do it in the same pagelayout

Comment: Can we ale to make it possible through formula fields or permission sets.Is there any possibility to do by using that.

Comment: @user36442 Unfortunately not. I've thought about some ideas salesforce.com could implement, like using a formula to determine each button's visibility, but we don't currently have any feature like that available. Even Permission Sets won't help in this case. It might be worth asking more specific questions, perhaps we can find an alternative for you?

Comment: is it possible through record types

Comment: @user36442 It depends on exactly what you're doing, but record types and profile combinations can select specific page layouts. You just can't do everything in a single page layout.